# Fail to connect to camera service on G1

Tags: android

I apologize in advance for this long post, but it's necessary to show what is happening.

I've been working on an app that works on the 1.6 emulator, but bombs on my G1.

Here is the Photographer activity:

```
public class Photographer extends Activity {

 private SurfaceView preview = null;
 private SurfaceHolder previewHolder = null;
 private Camera camera = null;
 public static final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 320;
 public static final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 480;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.photographer);

  preview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
  previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
  previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
  previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
 }

 private void takePicture() {
  camera.stopPreview();
  camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
 }

 SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
   camera = Camera.open();

   try {
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
   }
   catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("Photographer", "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
   }
   try {
    takePicture();
   } catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("Photographer", "Exception in takePicture()", t);
   }
  }

  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
         int format, int width, int height) {
   Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
   parameters.setPreviewSize(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
   parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
   camera.setParameters(parameters);
   camera.startPreview();
  }

  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
   camera.stopPreview();
   camera.release();
   camera = null;
  }
 };

 Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
   new SavePhotoTask().execute(data);
   camera.startPreview();
  }
 };

 class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(byte[]... jpeg) {
   File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "WIIA-new.jpg");
   if (photo.exists())
    photo.renameTo(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "WIIA-old.jpg"));

   try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());

    fos.write(jpeg[0]);
    fos.close();
    Log.e("Photographer", "Picture taken");
    // returning result
      Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
      setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);     
      finish();
   }
   catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    Log.e("Photographer", "Exception in photoCallback", e);

    // returning result
      Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
    finish();
   }

   return(null);
  }
 }

}
```

and here is where this activity gets called from:

```
    public class WIIA extends Activity {

 public class CountDown extends CountDownTimer {
  private TextView tvCountDown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progress);
  private TextView tvSystemState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.system_state);

  public CountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
   super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish() {
   tvSystemState.setText(R.string.system_state_armed);
   tvCountDown.setText(R.string.armed);
   snapshotInterval = Long.parseLong(settings.getString("snapshot_interval_list", "5"));
   imgCaptureTimer = new Timer("imageCapture");
   imgCaptureTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(doRefresh, 0, snapshotInterval*1000);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
   tvCountDown.setText(millisUntilFinished/1000 + " seconds until Armed");
  }

 }

 private TimerTask doRefresh = new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {
   if (armed) {
    refreshImage();
   } else {
    imgCaptureTimer.cancel();
   }
  }
 };

 private void refreshImage() {
  Thread updateThread = new Thread(null, backgroundCaptureImage, "capture_image");  
  updateThread.start();        
 }

 private Runnable backgroundCaptureImage = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
   doRefreshImage();
  }        
 };

 private void doRefreshImage() {
  Intent photographer = new Intent(this, Photographer.class);
  startActivityForResult(photographer, GET_PHOTO);
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  switch(requestCode) {
   case (GET_PHOTO) : {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    // go on to compare images
     new ProcessImageTask().execute();
    }
    break;
   }
  }
 }
```

Having trouble pasting the relevant portions of AndroidManifest.xml, but I have permissions for Camera:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

here's the Photographer part:

```
      <activity android:name=".Photographer"
   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
  </activity>
```

also set for testing on G1:

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

and working off of 1.6:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

All this works on a 1.6 emulator, but when I run this on the G1, LogCat shows:

```
INFO/ActivityManager(74): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.androidsecurity.wiia/.Photographer }

WARN/WindowManager(74): App freeze timeout expired.

WARN/WindowManager(74): Force clearing freeze: AppWindowToken{432e1520 token=HistoryRecord{43124c10 com.androidsecurity.wiia/.Photographer}}

WARN/ActivityManager(74): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43124c10 com.androidsecurity.wiia/.Photographer}

ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(51): native_get_picture: MSM_CAM_IOCTL_GET_PICTURE fd 13 error Connection timed out

ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(51): getPicture failed!

DEBUG/QualcommCameraHardware(51): snapshot_thread X

INFO/QualcommCameraHardware(51): initPreview E: preview size=480x320

DEBUG/QualcommCameraHardware(51): frame_thread E

DEBUG/CameraService(51): CameraService::connect E (pid 1031, client 0x3b510)

DEBUG/CameraService(51): CameraService::connect X (pid 1031, new client 0x3b510) rejected. (old pid 1031, old client 0x3b2e0)

DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1031): Shutting down VM

WARN/dalvikvm(1031): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001da28)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:67)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at com.androidsecurity.wiia.Photographer$1.surfaceCreated(Photographer.java:78)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:392)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:264)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1524)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1256)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1524)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1256)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6277)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1883)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1332)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1097)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1613)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and /data/anr/traces.txt shows:

```
`DALVIK THREADS:
"main" prio=5 tid=3 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001db08 self=0xbc48
  | sysTid=358 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=-1343996920
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationError(ActivityManagerNative.java:2243)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.crash(RuntimeInit.java:302)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:75)
  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:887)
  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:884)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"imageCapture" prio=5 tid=17 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x432a66f0 self=0x1dc820
  | sysTid=366 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=1938080
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x1c8cd8> (a java.util.Timer$TimerImpl)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:326)
  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:250)

"Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4327aa38 self=0x160ea0
  | sysTid=365 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=1406616
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4327a978 self=0x1609c0
  | sysTid=364 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=498392
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x432799d0 self=0x155268
  | sysTid=363 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=1397288
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=9 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x432782a0 self=0x15f788
  | sysTid=361 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=1614352
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=7 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x432781e8 self=0x18a0f0
  | sysTid=360 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=1614000
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x422dd3e8 self=0x1177a8
  | sysTid=359 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=1613728
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)`
```

It sounds like the problem is a timeout issue, but I am at a loss as to where I should be looking .... does anyone have a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's fantastic that I'm still hitting this problem in 2015.

Answer (score 15):

Most probably the cameraService which is part of the media process has crashed in the background. If you just try to run the default camera app in android and it does not show up then simply reboot the device to get this error off.

Comment: Is there anyway to fix this issue in code, I'm catching the exception but can't exactly tell a user to restart their device.

Comment: This also worked for me, but what sgarman is saying I cant tell a user to reboot his phone.

Answer (score 6):

Try to define the permission tag outside the application tag, like this:

```
<manifest ......>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity ...
                  .....>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not call stopPreview prior to takePicture.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

> 6.Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface.
>   Preview must be started before you can
>   take a picture.

```
 private void takePicture() {
  // WRONG: camera.stopPreview();
  camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
 }
```